# Formula Fields with Images in the Field Service Mobile App

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice, salesforce-mobile-app

I am trying to get images to appear in my formula field as described in this article in the Salesforce Field Service Mobile App:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&type=5

The formula fields work fine in Salesforce but I get the text of the link in the Field Service Mobile app (with no image), is there any way to get this to work out of the box in the Field Service app?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_limits.htm&type=5), Image in formula field will not show up in Field service mobile app. Check limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkJNUAZ/fsl-dispatcher-console-service-appointment-list-support-formula-images) and vote for this feature.

However you can create a flow to capture images from the Field service mobile app, more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_flow_image_upload.htm&type=5).

Thanks